# What does "on gets someone..." mean?

Tags: word-meaning

"Imagine the scene: you are sitting on the tube and **on gets** someone you instinctively feel is American. To make sure you ask them the time, and are right, but how did you know?"

I tried but couldn't find out what "on gets" really is. I've never seen it before. Is it a syntactical trick?

I truly need your help.

Answer (score 1):

> You are sitting on the tube and *on gets someone*...

This type of word order is called **subject-verb inversion**.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English#:%7E:text=Subject%E2%80%93verb%20inversion%20in%20English%20is%20a%20type%20of%20inversion,is%20not%20an%20auxiliary%20verb.) explains such inversions, including the **directive** one, and their uses.

> Subject-verb inversion[s]...emphasize the **post-verb subject**...,for instance, to establish a **contrast of the subject with another entity** in the discourse context.

The inversion in OP's example is the **directive inversion**.

> A predicative phrase is switched from its default postverbal position to a position preceding the verb...the pre-verb expression denotes a location...the verb is...a **verb of movement**.
>
> The fronted expression that evokes inversion is a **directive expression**; it helps **express movement toward a destination**.

> a. **Two students came** into the room.
>
> b. Into the room **came two students**. - Directive inversion

Answer (score -2):

It's a strange word order of "someone gets on". I certainly consider the OP phrasing awkward at the very least.

Comment: The syntax is nof strange at all.  It is a fairly common mode of speech.